# Ember don't override the model hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to the docs:

> If you're using Ember Data, you only need to override the model hook
>   if you need to return a model different from the record with the
>   provided ID

But this does not work for me, ember data gives me wrong data.

```
App.UsersEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: (params) ->
            return ['Just', 'Some', 'Random']
    setupController: (controller, model) ->
            controller.set('model', model) # Returns @get('store').find 'user', params.user_id
```

This should return ['Just', 'Some', Random], but instead it gives me the original @get('store').find 'user', params.user_id

Why and how do I get the data I want?
Btw, If I do like below, everything works, but I want to know why my model function never is called.

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('model', ['Just', 'Some', 'Random']) # returns ['Just', 'Some', 'Random']
```

Thank you, I'm using ember-data 0.14 and ember 1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model hook, for routes with a dynamic segment, is only called when the page is (re)loaded, here's what the [ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models) says (the note at the end):

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to override the model hook. The answer from Simon gave me the right direction. In addition, it should be noted, also from the ember guide but in the [Links](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) section, that the {{link-to}} helper takes:

> At most one model for each dynamic segment. By default, Ember.js will
>   replace each segment with the value of the corresponding object's id
>   property. If there is no model to pass to the helper, you can provide
>   an explicit identifier value instead. The value will be filled into
>   the dynamic segment of the route, and will make sure that the model
>   hook is triggered.

So the bottom line is that by replacing the model in the {{link-to}} helper (in my case 'product') by the object id (in my case 'product.id'), my model hook is now called every time.